# Getting key of inserted object in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do i retrieve the key of a newly inserted object in firebase..
The Object was inserted using android using setValue()

```
firebaseDatabaseRef.push().setValue(user);
```

Where user is a java object..

I need to key to update an attribute in my object.

The firebase ref is already pointing at the node in which the children are added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the key:

```
String Key = firebaseDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
```

then you can set value:

```
firebaseDatabaseRef.child(Key).setValue(YourValue);
```

Comment: Thank you,i cant believe I didnt figure this one out